# Why subsetting rows with 'apply' in data frame doesn't work in R

Tags: r, dataframe, selection

I have a data that looks like [this](http://dpaste.com/1215552/plain/).

```
Name|ID|p72|p78|p51|p49|c36.1|c32.1|c32.2|c36.2|c37
hsa-let-7a-5p|MIMAT0000062|9.1|38|12.7|185|8|4.53333333333333|17.9|23|63.3
hsa-let-7b-5p|MIMAT0000063|11.3|58.6|27.5|165.6|20.4|8.5|21|30.2|92.6
hsa-let-7c|MIMAT0000064|7.8|40.2|9.6|147.8|11.8|4.53333333333333|15.4|17.7|62.3
hsa-let-7d-5p|MIMAT0000065|4.53333333333333|27.7|13.4|158.1|8.5|4.53333333333333|14.2|13.5|50.5
hsa-let-7e-5p|MIMAT0000066|6.2|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|28|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|5.6|4.7|12.8
hsa-let-7f-5p|MIMAT0000067|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|78.2|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|6.8|4.53333333333333|8.9
hsa-miR-15a-5p|MIMAT0000068|4.53333333333333|70.3|10.3|147.6|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|21.1|30.2|100.8
hsa-miR-16-5p|MIMAT0000069|9.5|562.6|60.5|757|25.1|4.53333333333333|89.4|142.9|613.9
hsa-miR-17-5p|MIMAT0000070|10.5|71.6|27.4|335.1|6.3|10.1|51|51|187.1
hsa-miR-17-3p|MIMAT0000071|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|17.2|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|9.5|4.53333333333333|7.3
hsa-miR-18a-5p|MIMAT0000072|4.53333333333333|14.6|4.53333333333333|53.4|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|9.5|25.5|29.7
hsa-miR-19a-3p|MIMAT0000073|4.53333333333333|11.6|4.53333333333333|42.8|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|5.5|17.9
hsa-miR-19b-3p|MIMAT0000074|8.3|93.3|15.8|248.3|4.53333333333333|6.3|44.7|53.2|135
hsa-miR-20a-5p|MIMAT0000075|4.53333333333333|75.2|23.4|255.7|6.6|4.53333333333333|43.8|38|130.3
hsa-miR-21-5p|MIMAT0000076|6.2|19.7|18|299.5|6.8|4.53333333333333|49.9|68.5|48
hsa-miR-22-3p|MIMAT0000077|40.4|128.4|65.4|547.1|56.5|33.4|104.9|84.1|248.3
hsa-miR-23a-3p|MIMAT0000078|58.3|99.3|58.6|617.9|36.6|21.4|107.1|125.5|120.9
hsa-miR-24-1-5p|MIMAT0000079|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|9.2|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|4.53333333333333|4.9|4.53333333333333
hsa-miR-24-3p|MIMAT0000080|638.2|286.9|379.5|394.4|307.8|240.4|186|234.2|564
```

What I want to do is to simply pick rows where all the values is greater than 10.
But why this code of mine only report the last one? 
The data clearly showed that there are more rows that satisfy this condition.

```
> dat<-read.delim("http://dpaste.com/1215552/plain/",sep="|",na.strings="",header=TRUE,blank.lines.skip=TRUE,fill=FALSE)
```

But why this code of mine only report the last one?

```
> dat[apply(dat[, -1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) all(x > 10)), ]
            Name           ID   p72   p78   p51   p49 c36.1 c32.1 c32.2 c36.2 c37
19 hsa-miR-24-3p MIMAT0000080 638.2 286.9 379.5 394.4 307.8 240.4   186 234.2 564
```

What is the right way to do it?

**Update:**
alexwhan solution works. But I wonder how can I generalized his approach
so that it can handle data with missing values (NA)

```
dat<-read.delim("http://dpaste.com/1215354/plain/",sep="\t",na.strings="",heade‌​r=FALSE,blank.lines.skip=TRUE,fill=FALSE)
```

Comment: If you have NA's, then `... all( x[!is.na(x)] > 10) )`

Comment: BTW ... "doesn't work" is too vague to be meaningful. It should be stricken from computer-related discourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're including your `ID` column (which is a factor) in the `all()`, it's getting messed up. Try:

```
dat[apply(dat[, -c(1,2)], MARGIN = 1, function(x) all(x > 10)), ]

#              Name           ID   p72   p78   p51   p49 c36.1 c32.1 c32.2 c36.2   c37
# 16  hsa-miR-22-3p MIMAT0000077  40.4 128.4  65.4 547.1  56.5  33.4 104.9  84.1 248.3
# 17 hsa-miR-23a-3p MIMAT0000078  58.3  99.3  58.6 617.9  36.6  21.4 107.1 125.5 120.9
# 19  hsa-miR-24-3p MIMAT0000080 638.2 286.9 379.5 394.4 307.8 240.4 186.0 234.2 564.0
```

---

**EDIT**

For the case where you have `NA`, you can just just use the `na.rm` argument for `all()`. Using your new data (from the comment):

```
dat<-read.delim("http://dpaste.com/1215354/plain/",sep="\t",na.strings="",header=FALSE,blank.lines.skip=TRUE,fill=FALSE)
dat[apply(dat[, -c(1,2)], MARGIN = 1, function(x) all(x > 10, na.rm = T)), ]

#                V1           V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11
# 7  hsa-miR-15a-5p MIMAT0000068    NA  70.3  10.3 147.6    NA    NA  21.1  30.2 100.8
# 16  hsa-miR-22-3p MIMAT0000077  40.4 128.4  65.4 547.1  56.5  33.4 104.9  84.1 248.3
# 17 hsa-miR-23a-3p MIMAT0000078  58.3  99.3  58.6 617.9  36.6  21.4 107.1 125.5 120.9
# 19  hsa-miR-24-3p MIMAT0000080 638.2 286.9 379.5 394.4 307.8 240.4 186.0 234.2 564.0
# 20  hsa-miR-25-3p MIMAT0000081  19.3  78.6  25.6  84.3  14.9  16.9  19.1  27.2 113.8
# 21 hsa-miR-26a-5p MIMAT0000082    NA  22.8  31.0 561.2  12.4    NA  67.0  55.8  48.9
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works. But how can I generalized your approach so that it can handle data with missing values?
`dat<-read.delim("http://dpaste.com/1215354/plain/",sep="\t",na.strings="",header=FALSE,blank.lines.skip=TRUE,fill=FALSE)`

Comment: @neversaint see if the edit works for you. I haven't been able to figure out why `dat[,19]` returns `TRUE` for your first example - it seems very strange. Might be worth a separate question

Answer (score 1):

ANother idea is to transform your data ton **long** format( or molton format). I think it is even better to avoid  missing values  problem with:

```
library(reshape2)
dat.m <- melt(dat,id.vars=c('Name','ID'))
dat.m$value <- as.numeric(dat.m$value)
library(plyr)
res <- ddply(dat.m,.(Name,ID), summarise, keepme = all(value > 10))
res[res$keepme,]
# Name           ID keepme
# 16  hsa-miR-22-3p MIMAT0000077   TRUE
# 17 hsa-miR-23a-3p MIMAT0000078   TRUE
# 19  hsa-miR-24-3p MIMAT0000080   TRUE
```

Comment: I guess it depends here on whether the OP wants `NA` to cause the logical test to fail or not - just realised that's not clear in the question.